# how to add the data in @html.listbox using mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor, listbox

i need to add the value in my list box using mvc and razor view. my code is given below:

razor view :

```
function buttonchk() {

            $.ajax({

                success: function (data) { // in data i have the value 
                            // here what code i put?
                }
            });
        }

      @Html.ListBox("test", Model.value, new { @class = "test1" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `append`:

```
function buttonchk() {
        $.ajax({
            success: function (data) { // in data i have the value 
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                   $("#test").append("<option value=" + data.value + ">" + data.value + "</option>"
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: list of values returned from the ajax call?